# Prevent Cross-site scripting

Tags: 8, security

One of the security principles is sanitizing strings and variables passed from client to server. In plain PHP there are some functions to prevent XSS ([Cross-site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))) vulnerabilities:

- [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
- [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

What is Drupal 8 strategy to prevent XSS  attacks? How can I clean up client data post to protect my site from XSS attacks?

I remember Drupal 7 has [`filter_xss()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/filter_xss/7.x) to prevent XSS vulnerabilities, but what is Drupal 8 strategy against XSS vulnerabilities?

Comment: Also, look into defining a Content-Security-Policy header for your site, as an additional layer of XSS protection (https://www.drupal.org/project/csp).  Unfortunately Drupal 8 is not yet able to block inline scripts completely due to it use of CKEditor 4, but recent updates to the CSP spec will at least allow narrowing which inline scripts are allowed once adopted by browsers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> #### Sanitizing on output to avoid Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks
>
> **Use Twig templates** The Twig theme engine now auto escapes everything by default. That means that every string printed from a
>   Twig template (e.g. anything between `{{ }}`) **gets automatically
>   sanitized *if no filters are used.***
>
> See [Filters - Modifying Variables In Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/2357633) for the Twig
>   filters available in Drupal.
>
> In order to take advantage of Twig’s automatic escaping (and avoid
>   safe markup being escaped) ideally all HTML should be outputted from
>   Twig templates.
>
> API functions Use [t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/t) and `\Drupal::translation()->formatPlural()`
>   with `@` or `%` placeholders to construct safe, translatable strings. See
>   [Code text translation API in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/localization) for more details.
>
> - Use [Html::escape()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3Aescape/8) for plain text.
> - Use [Xss::filter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.php/function/Xss%3A%3Afilter/8) for text that should allow some HTML tags.
> - Use [Xss::filterAdmin()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Component!Utility!Xss.php/class/Xss) for text entered by a admin users that should allow most HTML.
>
> **Strings sanitized by t(), Html::escape(), Xss::filter() or
>   Xss::filterAdmin() are automatically marked safe, as are markup
>   strings created from render arrays via [Renderer](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/class/Renderer/8.4.x).**
>
> While it can also sanitize text, it's almost never correct to use
>   check_markup in a theme or module except in the context of something
>   like a text area with an associated text format.

Source: **[Drupal 8: Writing secure code](https://www.drupal.org/node/2489544)** by: Rade, Shyamala, Robert Castelo, and Pere Orga.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal generally takes the approach of filtering on output, not on input.

A module which accepts a person's input as not part of the field system must filter it when it outputs it (even from privileged, administrator users).  Output is usually a render array.  So a simple way to do this is to limit allowed tags on render.  To take an example from [taxonomy module's output of a term label](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Controller%21TaxonomyController.php/8.5.x):

```
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss;
```

...

```
  public function termTitle(TermInterface $taxonomy_term) {
    return [
      '#markup' => $taxonomy_term->getName(),
      '#allowed_tags' => Xss::getHtmlTagList(),
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Twig templates did not sanitize output in my application. A script string or XSS attack entered into a comment field and saved was executed when the page loaded. Instead, I solved the problem by sanitizing each string input field in `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load`.

```
 if(isset($entity->$fieldName)) {  
        $value = $entity->get($fieldName)->value;  
        $value =  htmlspecialchars($value);  
        $entity->set($fieldName, $value);  
 }
```